# SolrIndexerJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed:

Tags: apache, nutch

The Apache nutch \ "crawl" scripts fails on indexing to solr. Any thought on this?

```
IndexingJob: starting
SolrIndexerJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=[myId_1]Indexer, jobid=job_local483340309_0001
        at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:120)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:154)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:176)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:211)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is not very informative, check/post the Solr log for any relevant error. One of the usual causes for this is a mismatch between the Nutch and Solr schemas.

Comment: 10x - solr logs claimed meta_description should be multivalued - changed - and now it is working